# Add a word break tag after every 12th character in a string

Tags: php, html, string

```
$my_string = "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry."
```

Expected result :

```
"Lorem Ipsum <br/> is simply<br/> dummy text<br/>of the printing<br/> and typesetting<br/> industry."
```

Tag should be added after every 12th character and not like this :

```
There are ma<br/>ny variations
```

Comment: You mean after 12 words?

Comment: are you sure you need to add `br` and not use CSS for text wrapping?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Give it a try with [**wordwrap**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.wordwrap.php). I think it should solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$newtext = wordwrap($text,12, "<br />");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$text = "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.";
$newtext = wordwrap($text, 12, "<br />\n");

echo $newtext;
```

Output:

```
Lorem Ipsum
is simply
dummy text
of the
printing and
typesetting
industry. 


http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.wordwrap.php
```

Comment: don't copy off the php.net website!

Comment: yes its working, but not working if i use chinese character(language)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6527880/php-wordwrap-cut-parameter-when-dealing-with-weird-characters

Answer (score 0):

Just expanding on Shakti's answer with an example:

```
$my_string = "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.";
$my_wrapped_string = wordwrap($my_string, 12, '<br />');
```

The value of `$my_wrapped_string` would then be `Lorem Ipsum<br />is simply<br />dummy text<br />of the<br />printing and<br />typesetting<br />industry.`

Answer (score 0):

Your expected result seems quite inconsistent in terms of spaces and the breaks. Sounds like you want some custom solution, is something like this more what you're after:

```
$array = $my_string.explode(" ");

counter = 0;
for(index=0; index<array.length; index++){
    counter += array[index].length+1;
    if(counter > 12){
        array[index-1] += "<br>"; //put some error handling here
        counter = 0;
    }
}

//then convert back to string and do whatever 
// - I tested this in JS and it worked fine
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$text = "A very long woooooooooooooooooord. and something";
$newtext = wordwrap($text, 8, "\n", false);

echo "$newtext\n";
?>
```

The above example will output:

```
A very
long
woooooooooooooooooord.
and
something
```

Comment: $str = "An example of a long word is: Supercalifragulistic";
echo wordwrap($str,12,"<br>\n");